# ARSessionOrigin transform position and rotation to make created ARTrackedImage become Unity space zero

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I'm using `ARFoundation` with tracking images(Image Library has only one image to find).
When the image is found I'm subscribing on that event with

```
[SerializeField]
ARTrackedImageManager _arTrackedImageManager;

void Awake()
{
    _arTrackedImageManager.trackedImagesChanged += ImageChangedHandle;
}

void ImageChangedHandle(ARTrackedImagesChangedEventArgs imgChangedArgs)
{
    foreach (var item in imgChangedArgs.added)
    {
        var go = item.gameObject;

        _arkitChecker.DisplayFoundTrackedImage(item);
    }
}
```

_arkitChecker is instance of my class with DisplayFoundTrackedImage method :

```
internal void DisplayFoundTrackedImage(ARTrackedImage targetImageGameObject)
{
    var arOrig = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<ARSessionOrigin>();

    arOrig.transform.Translate(-targetImageGameObject.transform.position, Space.World);

    float babyAngle;
    Vector3 babyAxis;
    targetImageGameObject.transform.rotation.ToAngleAxis(out babyAngle, out babyAxis);

    arOrig.transform.RotateAround(Vector3.zero, babyAxis, -babyAngle);
}
```

As a result I want to make transformation when created `ARTrackedImage` becomes Unity space `Vector3.zero` with `Quaternion.identity`, but on the device image nothink changes.

I've also tried ARSessionOrigin.MakeContentAppearAt, but didnt work as I want :

```
arOrig.MakeContentAppearAt(targetImageGameObject.transform, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had to solve this same problem, I was able to make it work with the `ARSessionOrigin` `MakeContentAppearAt()` method, using the tracked image's position and rotation (I'm using ARFoundation v3.0.0 preview 4).

That method is not documented very well, after some trial and error I have found that you need to use the `localRotation` of the tracked image, not the world-space `rotation` otherwise the orientation will be incorrect.

Whenever the tracked image is found or updated, I run the following:

```cs
void OnTrackedImagesChanged(ARTrackedImagesChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if(eventArgs.updated.Count > 0)
    {
        ARTrackedImage trackedImage = eventArgs.updated[0];
        arSessionOrigin.MakeContentAppearAt(worldOrigin.transform, trackedImage.transform.position, trackedImage.transform.localRotation);
    }
}
```

`worldOrigin.transform` is just an empty game object at position 0,0,0 with no rotation.

So, this code is saying: I want the worldOrigin transform to *appear as if* it is located at the trackedImage position/rotation by adjusting the AR camera's transform to compensate (`worldOrigin.transform` is not modified).